# sql - stored procedure Incorrect syntax near 'itemview'

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

```
declare @query nvarchar(4000)   

set @query='SELECT InsightsLogs.ContentItemType, COUNT(InsightsLogs.UserId) AS nbr, CONT_COMP.MAIN'
set @query= @query + ' FROM InsightsLogs INNER JOIN CONT_COMP ON InsightsLogs.K_Contact = CONT_COMP.K_CONTACT'
set @query= @query + ' WHERE  InsightsLogs.EventType =N"'itemview'" AND (InsightsLogs.K_Contact IS NOT NULL) AND (CONT_COMP.K_COMPANY <> 1) AND (CONT_COMP.MAIN = 1)'
--set @query= @query + ' AND (Date_Visite >= CONVERT(DATETIME, "' + @date1 + ' 00:00:00", 102))'
--set @query= @query + ' AND (Date_Visite < CONVERT(DATETIME, "' + @date2 + ' 00:00:00", 102))'
set @query= @query + ' GROUP BY dbo.InsightsLogs.UserId'
exec sp_executesql @query
```

how do i modify the itemview??? always the same message, incorrect syntax near itemview

InsightsLogs.EventType =N"'itemview'"

thx

Comment: What is itemview? And why are you using dynamic sql here? And if you do use dynamic sql you don't have to keep using set over and over. Have you read about parameters?

Comment: i have a table with a lot or records, and i need only the records in the column "eventtype" with the filter "itemview"

Comment: What does that mean? Are you looking for that as a string literal? And again...why dynamic sql here??? Those two lines you have commented out are a real issue too.

Comment: the query in sql is    SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT InsightsLogs.ContentItemType, COUNT(InsightsLogs.UserId) AS Expr1, CONT_COMP.MAIN
FROM     InsightsLogs INNER JOIN
                  CONT_COMP ON InsightsLogs.K_Contact = CONT_COMP.K_CONTACT
WHERE  (CONT_COMP.K_COMPANY <> 1) AND (CONT_COMP.MAIN = 1) AND (InsightsLogs.EventType = N'itemview') AND (InsightsLogs.K_Contact IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY InsightsLogs.UserId                                                       how i convert it to storedprocedure?

Comment: Code in comments is not a good plan. It should be part of your question. Not to mention that the formatting in comments is useless for code.

Comment: You really need to provide us with some details. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of double-quotes:

```
=N"'itemview'"
```

Use two single quotes:

```
=N''itemview''
```

Comment: same problem   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near 'itemview'.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what you are trying to do here or why you need dynamic sql. I suspect you are using dynamic sql not because it is needed but because you are unsure how to do this. I attempted to sort this query out. Notice that by using a little formatting and some aliases this is really easy to see what is going on instead of everything piled up as a wall of text.

```
SELECT il.ContentItemType
    , COUNT(il.UserId) AS nbr
    , c.MAIN
FROM InsightsLogs il
INNER JOIN CONT_COMP c ON il.K_Contact = c.K_CONTACT
WHERE  il.EventType =N'itemview' 
    AND il.K_Contact IS NOT NULL 
    AND c.K_COMPANY <> 1
    AND c.MAIN = 1
    --AND (Date_Visite >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @date1 + ' 00:00:00', 102))
    --AND (Date_Visite < CONVERT(DATETIME, @date2 + ' 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY il.UserId , c.MAIN
```

Now if you need that as a stored procedure you simply have this query as the body of your procedure.

Comment: You still need to add `c.MAIN` to the `group by`. And what is `dbo.il.UserId`? `il` is the alias, so the `dbo.` seems wrong. Good effort, but too little context and info from OP.

Comment: @HoneyBadger thanks for the catch. It seems the OP was inconsistent about using the schema in those. I used find-replace to add aliases. And didn't look closely at the group by. But who knows? This is a guess work at best since we have nothing in the way of details.